# Read keyboard input to clipboard

Tags: clipboard

I would like to be able to run `read -s` on the command line and send input to one of the three clipboards.

Instead of

```
$ read -s password 
$ echo $password | xclip -sel p
```

I would like to

```
$ read -s | xclip -sel p
```

How can I do this. The above example doesn't work.

Comment: What about `read -s password && echo $password | xclip -sel p` ?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, @vanadium

Comment: That is not fundamentally different from what you asked in your question, execpt that it is written as a one liner. This is why I did not post this as an answer, because your real problem is not clear.

Comment: Valid point. What I was hoping was not to have a variable (password) hanging around with the password and after running the following (portion of script) I manually clear password variable (not desired)
**
if [[ $1 == "-i" ]]; then
        ## Interactive mode
        read -p "file to mount: " file
        echo "password: "
        stty -echo
        read password && echo $password | xsc;
        stty echo
        read -p "keyfile: " keyfile

        sudo veracrypt --text --mount $file --password `xsv` --pim 0 --keyfiles $keyfile --protect-hidden no
**

Comment: That code snippet came out as a one-liner. Sorry about that